# How to keep resources on the cluster when uninstalling a release?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Is there's a way to NOT remove certain resources from the cluster when uninstalling releases, and to re-use them (without conflict) when re-installing?

I was thinking of resources such as secrets and persistent volumes

Answer (score 7):

You can [Tell Helm Not To Uninstall a Resource](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#tell-helm-not-to-uninstall-a-resource) by adding the following annotation:

```
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/resource-policy": keep
```

Comment: For others coming across this and thinking this is a solution: This is not possible due to a bug in `helm` (open since 2022) https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/10890. Even with the annotation, the resources will be deleted when running `helm uninstall`.